# Setting return value of char pointer to a char array

Tags: c, pointers

Trying to learn C. To that end, I'm coding a program that creates a TroubleTicket report. The user is prompted to enter, priority, name and problem. I'm using a struct to store the data and create a struck array. Using the array approach for now as I'm developing the code. Eventually, I'd to use a linked list.

Anyhow, the get_input() function reads in the user input and returns a char pointer.
Included the get_input() and create_ticket() functions.

```
#define NUM_TICKETS 10

char* get_input(int maxlen)
{
    static char s[110];
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int chars_remain = 1;

    while (chars_remain)
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if ((ch == '\n') || (ch == EOF))
        {
            chars_remain = 0;
        }
        else if (i < maxlen - 1)
        {
            s[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return s;
    
void create_ticket()
{
    struct ticket
    {
        int priority;
        int number;
        char * name;
        char * problem ;
        char * assigned_to;
        char * status ;
    };
    struct ticket tkt_array[NUM_TICKETS];
    struct ticket new_ticket;
    
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    new_ticket.name = get_input(20);
    printf("new_ticket.name: %s \n", new_ticket.name);
        
    printf("Enter problem description: ");
    new_ticket.problem = get_input(100);
    printf("new_ticket.problem: %s \n", new_ticket.problem);
    
    printf("Assigned to: ");
    new_ticket.assigned_to = get_input(20);
    printf("new_ticket.assigned_to %s\n ", new_ticket.assigned_to);
    
    printf("Enter ticket status: ");
    new_ticket.status = get_input(10);
    printf("new_ticket.status: %s \n", new_ticket.status);
    
}
```

I noticed that initial input was read and displayed correctly but subsequent inputs overwrote prior input.

For example, after name was entered, the entered value is displayed

```
printf("Enter your name: ");
new_ticket.name = get_input(20);
printf("new_ticket.name: %s \n", new_ticket.name);
```

But after problem description is entered, new_ticket.name was changed to display the problem description text. Took me a while to figure out that the problem is the return s in get_char(). It returns a pointer. The address is the same but the value changes and struct ticket pointers point to the same address of return s from get_char().
How can I save the return value in a variable and not get it reset on subsequent call to get_input?
s is a char *, how can I save the return value of a pointer in a variable?

```
printf("Enter problem description: ");
new_ticket.problem = get_input(100);
printf("new_ticket.problem: %s \n", new_ticket.problem);
printf("new_ticket.name: %s \n", new_ticket.name);
```

How can I save the return value in a variable and not get it reset on subsequent call to get_input?
s is a char *, how can I save the return value of a pointer in a variable?
I hope I clearly stated the issue.

Comment: Please note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns and **`int`** value. This is rather important when you want to compare it with the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: *Where* do you want to save the string?

Comment: As for your problem, the `static` array in `get_input`, I recommend that you create an array in the *calling* function and pass it in to the `get` input instead: `char *get_input(char *buffer, size_t buflen);`

Comment: By the way, you *do* understand the meaning and semantics of local `static` variables in functions?

Comment: Andrew, Missing `}` before `void create_ticket()`.  Please review posted code for compilation correctness.

Comment: Andrew, when `char` is _unsigned_, `ch == EOF` is never true.  Use `int ch`.

Comment: Static allowed me to return s. The code I posted is a snipped from two files. It does compile and run. I'll try passing in an array instead of return. I'd like to save the string in create_ticket()

Comment: You have to decide where you want to save the string. Currently you store each string in the same place (which is a static variable - static meaning there's only one copy of it, not one per call). You might choose to make `struct ticket` have arrays in it instead of pointers, and store the strings in those arrays. Or you might choose to `malloc` some memory and store the string in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` keyword creates a value that exists once, so multiple invocations of the function point to the same data.

If you want to dynamically create data with a lifetime that you control, you may allocate your own memory.

`malloc(size)` will allocate a block of memory with the size provided. This memory will exist and be valid until you call `free` on that memory.

You should be careful though, calling `free` twice, or forgetting to call it at all, are common sources of bugs within c code.

The other option in this is to have the caller of the function provide the memory. You could change your `struct ticket` to have `char name[MAX_NAME_LEN]`, and update the function get input to `get_input(int max_len, char * buffer)`. This also solves the problem, while avoiding potentially erroneous `malloc` and `free`s.

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses only the problem stated in the question, not other errors or problems in your code.

Your function `get_input` uses a single array `static char s[110];` to store the input and always returns the address of this array.

Assignments like `new_ticket.name = get_input(20);` will store the same address in all pointer variables, so all will actually point to the same variable `s` which will contain the last input.

One option to solve this would be to replace the pointers in your structure with arrays and either pass this to `get_input` or copy the value using `strcpy`.

Or you could use the (non-standard) function `strdup` to get a dynamically allocated duplicate of the input string. If this function is not available, you could implement it using `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Example:

```
    new_ticket.name = strdup(get_input(20));
```

Note: When using `strdup`, you should `free` the memory when it's no longer needed.

or using a replacement for `strdup`:

```
    const char *s1;
    char *s2;
/* ... */

    s1 = get_input(20);
    s2 = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);
    if(s2 == NULL)
    {
        /* handle error */
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(s2, s1);
    }
    new_ticket.name = s2;
```

(You could implement your own function that wraps `malloc` and `strcpy`.)

or with arrays instead of pointers as structure fields

```
    struct ticket
    {
        int priority;
        int number;
        char name[20];
        char problem[100];
        char assigned_to[20];
        char status[10];
    };

/* ... */
    strcpy(new_ticket.name, get_input(sizeof(new_ticket.name));
```

Comment: I tried using arrays as the sample shows but stack size error message. That's why I used pointers

Comment: Ended up using strdup(). VS2019 complained and instructed to use _strdup so I just added #define strdup _strdup and code is working.

Comment: @Andrew This is because `strdup`  is in POSIX but not in the C standard. Note that you should `free` the memory allocated by `strdup` when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I didn't know I had to use free. I assumed that strdup() called free.